# How to pass in responses and key presses into a bash script

Tags: bash, terminal, aws-cli

I am trying to configure my aws sso account via a script. To do this I need to pass in strings (easy enough) AND press enter when it asks me to select a "role".

So far I have:

```sh
echo "foo\nbar\n" | aws configure sso --profile baz
```

The `foo` and `bar` responses sucessfully answer the two prompts, but the third prompt which wants me to press enter fails.

Can anyone provide help with this?

Comment: So you pipe in "foo<enter>" followed by "bar<enter>" and nothing more, and you're asking why it doesn't put in a third "<enter>"?

Comment: `echo "foo\nbar\n\n"`

Comment: I know I'm wrong but I was hoping the newline at the end would be the a third input and be equivalent to enter :) - could you tell me how I could echo/get the enter keypress to work?

Comment: The newline character `\n` is effectively the same as "pressing enter." Just add an additional newline character for the third prompt, as I suggested in a prior comment.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - I gave it a try and unfortunately no luck. I am now getting these errors:

`Warning: Output is not to a terminal (fd=1).`
`Warning: Input is not to a terminal (fd=0).`

I'm not sure if these are even related to my question now...

Comment: Consider writing an expect script (based on TCL).  Or using python expect (which I prefer).  Expect simulates a TTY for the process you are invoking.  In this way, you can send your responses to prompts and the process thinks it's talking to a TTY.

Comment: @clev These do not sound like errors. They sound like harmless warnings.

Comment: you can find it from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22387763/how-to-automatically-hit-enter-in-bash-script-when-asked/72697208#72697208